# How to write log in logcat file by filtering with keyword using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

Currently I'm capturing the logs that are generated while performing performance testing for an app. But the log file that is generated has all the logs of the device as well.

My ask is to filter out the logs that are getting captured with a specific keyword.

My approach is as follows -

```
call([adb, "logcat", "-c"])
with open(logcat_file_path, 'w') as out:
    logcat_process = Popen([adb, "logcat", " | ", "grep", "'facebook'"], stdout=out)
return logcat_process
```

But there is no luck! Can someone please help me out here

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

i tried the following way and it worked for me.

```
call([adb, "logcat", "-c"])
with open(logcat_file_path, 'w') as out:
    logcat_process = Popen([adb, "logcat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc1= Popen(["grep" , "facebook"], stdin=logcat_process.stdout, stdout=out)
return proc1
```

Answer (score 0):

A way cleaner solution would be to

- catch the log using adb logcat as you do
- read the log file as you do
- retrieve the informations you want and write it in another file

This way

- your code also works on other operating systems without grep
- it's safer because Popen must be replaced by python code directly as possible, and used only when there are no other solutions